# Proving $\alpha+(\beta+\gamma) = (\alpha+\beta)+\gamma$ for ordinals

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am following Jech's construction, by definition $\alpha+0 = \alpha, \alpha+(\beta+1)=(\alpha+\beta)+1$, and for limit $\beta$ we define $\alpha+\beta = \cup\{\alpha+\xi: \xi<\beta\}$.

Jech's proof of associativity just says "By induction on $\gamma$." so I am trying to go through it. The statement I am inducting on is $\forall \alpha,\beta \in Ord~ (\alpha+(\beta+\gamma) = (\alpha+\beta)+\gamma)$.

I have done $\gamma = 0$ and $\gamma=c+1$ and have left to show it holds for $\gamma$ a limit. In this case I would like to say
$$(\alpha+\beta)+\gamma = \cup\{(\alpha+\beta)+\xi:\xi < \gamma\}$$
$$
= \cup\{\alpha+(\beta+\xi):\xi < \gamma\}
$$
$$
= \alpha + \cup\{\beta+\xi:\xi<\gamma\}
$$
$$
= \alpha + (\beta+\gamma).
$$

However I have been stuck trying to show $
 \cup\{\alpha+(\beta+\xi):\xi < \gamma\}
= \alpha + \cup\{\beta+\xi:\xi<\gamma\}.
$

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For establishing your last statement, it suffices to prove two things (neither is hard):

- $\beta+\gamma$ is a limit ordinal;
- $\cup\{\alpha+(\beta+\xi):\xi<\gamma\} = \cup\{\alpha+\xi:\xi < \beta+\gamma\}$.

For, the right-hand side of this equality is precisely the definition of $\alpha+(\beta+\gamma)$ when $\beta+\gamma$ is a limit ordinal.

---

Alternatively, you can take the general route and prove that the composition of normal sequences is normal, and directly conclude that:

$$\sup_{\xi <\gamma}(\alpha +(\beta+\xi)) = \alpha+(\beta+\gamma)$$

because the sequences $\delta_\zeta = \alpha+\zeta$ and $\epsilon_\xi = \beta+\xi$ are both normal, and thus so is the sequence $\eta_\xi = \delta_{\epsilon_\xi} = \alpha + (\beta + \xi)$. This approach will save you time when dealing with the multiplication and exponentiation cases.

Comment: Really nice answer!  I learned much from it.  Also, I made some edits to it; please review them.  I hope they are OK; needless to say, I trust that you will revert any or all of them if they aren't.